# curly apostrophes in fancyvrb verbatim environments

Tags: verbatim, french, apostrophe

I am actually using the fancyvrb package to have verbatim environments with working commands inside.
I am also using the cmun.ttf font (computer modern unicode font), with XeTeX.

When I am using this font without verbatim environment, I have the good one curly apostrophe (’) (U+2019, ou U+02BC).

But, in fancyvrb verbatim environment, of course, I don't have them, but the typewriter one (').

How could I set the curly one as variant for the straight one automatically for verbatim environments ?

```
\documentclass[9pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec, fancyvrb}
\setmainfont{cmun} %what you want MONO font
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VRB}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
\begin{document}
\begin{VRB}
J'écris en \emph{français}.
\end{VRB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `upquote` package. I can't try it since I don't have your fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the mono font, otherwise you get the default Latin Modern without “TeX ligatures”. However, usually ligatures (and curly quotes) are not wanted in typewriter type.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec, fancyvrb}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}[Ligatures=TeX]

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VRB}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}

\begin{document}

J'écris en \emph{français}.

\begin{VRB}
J'écris en \emph{français}.
\end{VRB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, I just needed to add the Ligatures=TeX.
But as you said, it is not wanted usually in typewriter type.
Actually, I just need it for one of my Verbatim Environment. For another, I need the standard mono font (so without curly apostrophes).
So I looked for the fontfamily option of fancyvrb, but I don't know how to define the same mono font without ligature option).